# How to make SVG size equal to US letter / A4 size with 100% scale?

Tags: svg

I have created SVG, but it need scaling for A4/Letter size print, but I want it to make default size, so that I can print it without scaling in print options. Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SVG that has the same aspect ratio as the paper it will cover the entire page. Avoid defining height and width.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 210 297">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```